# Fortify for .net commandline tool causing error

Tags: c#, .net, fortify

I'm using Fortify 20.2 to analyze a .net 5 application using the command line tool.

In several examples and in the documentation I always see this :

```
sourceanalyzer -b MyProject -clear
sourceanalyzer -b MyProject msbuild /t:rebuild c:\MyProject\MyProject.sln
sourceanalyzer -b MyProject -scan -f c:\MyReports\MyReport.fpr
```

The second line is compiling the project

The last line is causing an error saying:

```
[error]: Unable to load build session with ID "MyProject". See log file for more details.
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Or where the log file is located?

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/fortify-static-code-analyzer-and-tools/2020/SCA_Guide_20.2.0.pdf), log files should be available at `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Fortify\sca<version>\log`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thanks for the hint. unfortunately not much more information in the log files.